# Does Big Query data transfer service uses a Service Account when run using composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

I am creating a bigquery transfer run using python and running it via composer using Python Operator. Will this setup internally use a Service account specific to the transfer service?

Answer (score 1):

There's no "find and use a suitable service account for my call" magic in composer.

When a [composer environment is created](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/composer/environments/create) a service account is specified [whose permissions are used when Google Cloud is accessed](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/authentication).  This is the service account which will be used, unless another account is configured by custom code inside the `PythonOperator`.  This service account will need to be authorized to access [`bigquery.transfers.update`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) if the Task Instances of the operator are going to have success.